# Why would one of the zones of my Slant Fin gas fired hot water baseboard heating system not be heating?

Tags: heating, thermostat

Thus far I have:

- replaced with new batteries.
- turned down temp and switched the breakers
- turned heat back up, no response

Can a pilot be out for one zone?  The other two are warm and cozy.
Did the pipes freeze? Or they use same pipes.  I answered my own question!
I lowered heat in zone 2 and 3 so more would go to zone 1.

Yesterday the power did go out in part of the kitchen. Did that affect zone 1 because the temperature was left at 65 the night before.

Comment: Could be a dead zone valve, bad zone controller (if there is one), air in the pipes, etc. If you're not familiar with the operation of the system, you might want to contact a local HVAC company.

Comment: Is there no heat in the zone, or just very little heat?